# Count coords dots in polygon

Tags: json, pandas, geolocation, coordinates, polygon

I would like to count the appearance of several dots in a prespecified polygons. I am loading the EU NUTS Region by

```
nuts = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/eurostat/Nuts2json/master/2016/4258/60M/nutsrg_2.json'
geo_json_nuts = json.loads(requests.get(nuts).text)
```

and I have a list of tuples or a DataFrame, which contains data as follows:

```
Index lon           lat
0     -178.1328187  -14.3087256
1     -176.2036596  -13.3469813
2     -176.1720255  -13.2789922
3     -151.3381037  -22.4532474
4     -151.0331577  -16.7159449
...   ...           ...
```

Now I would like to match the lon/lat in the DataFrame to the `Feature properties id` contained in `geo_json_nuts`. Meaning if lon/lat is contained in one of the polygons in `geo_json_nuts` it should get the properties id, e.g. BE31 or AT32, etc.

Does anyone know how to handle this?

Thank you in advance!

Best regards
Alex

Answer (score 0):

you can try to normalize your json file.

```
nuts = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/eurostat/Nuts2json/master/2016/4258/60M/nutsrg_2.json'
geo_json_nuts = json.loads(requests.get(nuts).text)
df = json_normalize(geo_json_nuts, 'features', ['coordinates'], 
                    errors='ignore',
                    record_prefix='features_')
```

After this process, you will have a dataframe contains 'features_properties.id' for the id and the features_geometry.coordinates for the points.

Comment: Hi @Pei Li, thank you for your reply! That is great, it works so far. However, I am not aware how I now can compare the dots (coordinates) with the polygons and count if the dot in located within the polygon. Do you know how to handle this? Thanks

Comment: @AlexanderHempfing Could you explain more? I'm not sure about your purpose.